# I'm getting "Unable to locate name/value separator for string" when setting up a command block to give a magic stick?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to set up a command block that is used to spawn in a  "magic wand" with knockback & fire aspect. I've got the spawning of the "wand" itself down, and I can do that no problem.

However, I wanted to add Lore and a custom title to the wand, as per [this tutorial/wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_Tags#Items), and came up with this command:

```
give @p minecraft:stick 1 0 {ench:[{id:19,lvl:10}],{display:{Name:"KAPOOYAH!",Lore:["You're a Wizard!","Tap someone to launch them across all of time and space"]}}}
```

However, when I put that in a command block and run it, I get no wand and this error:

```
[11:30:57] Data tag parsing failed: Unable to locate name/value separator for string: {display:{Name:"KAPOOYAH!",Lore:["You're a Wizard!","Tap someone to launch them across all of time and space"]}}
```

Does anyone know why my `display:{......` isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `display` tag to be within it's own set of braces; that would imply that it's a subtag of, well, nothing.  If I remove the braces that surround the `display` tag, the command works fine (other than not fitting in a chat line, but a command block solves that).

For future reference, all tags that exist at the same level are only separated by commas, where a set of braces indicates some kind of subset of tags.  The `ench` and `display` tags exist on the same level, and so should only be separated by a comma.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out and confirm that it works - if it does, I'll mark as answer!